# Gas requirement of function postrecord on retrunstring is high, anyone know how to bring it down?

Tags: remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract insure {
  address public doctor;

  function Person() private {
    doctor = msg.sender;
  }
  modifier onlyDoctor {
    require(msg.sender == doctor);
    _;
  }
}

contract postRecord is insure {
  string records;
  string patientRecords;

  struct patient {
      address client;
      bool consent;
      bytes32 name;
   }

  event Post(address doctor, string patientRecords);

  function modify() private onlyDoctor {
      records = patientRecords;
  }

  modifier rightPerson {
      if (msg.sender != doctor){
        throw;
      }else{
        _;
      }
  }
  function returnString()public payable{
     Post(doctor, patientRecords);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hem, I don't see any postRecord function

Answer (score 0):

Strings can be of unbounded length, so the gas cost of working with them is also unbounded.

That doesn't necessarily mean there's a problem, since in reality the strings are limited in length, but Solidity's warning is accurate.